# Error in default proguard.cfg?

Tags: android, eclipse, proguard

When I create a new Android project in Eclipse, the following default proguard.cfg file is created:

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
```

Note that the `-optimizations` line comments out the rest of the file. I'm wondering if it is intentional or if it is a typo and that line should have its last two characters reversed:

```
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging*/
```

I'm using ADT plugin 9.0 and Eclipse 3.6.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. I'm now feeling a little stupid. The answer is that nothing here is a comment. The line should be interpreted as if it were spaced out like this:

```
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,
               !field/*,
               !class/merging/*
```

The `*` is a wildcard character and the syntax highlighting done by the forum is wrong in this case.

Comment: how does one add comments to the proguard.cfg ? is it even possible ?

Comment: @Someone - that's in part why I feel stupid about this. The proguard.cfg file is just a substitute for putting command-line options on the command line (as the [ProGuard manual](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#/manual/gui.html) makes clear). Since there's no way to embed "comments" in the command line, there's probably no way to add comments to the file, either. Too bad, because the file can be pretty complex and comments could probably be helpful.

Comment: I believe lines beginning with `#` are comments.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you didn't accidently do that?

I just created a dummy project and ended up with this. I'd try to remove that line and see if that works.

```
-injars      bin/classes
-injars      libs
-outjars     bin/classes-processed.jar
-libraryjars /usr/local/java/android-sdk/platforms/android-9/android.jar

-dontpreverify
-repackageclasses ''
-allowaccessmodification
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic
-keepattributes *Annotation*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider

-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
    public void set*(...);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    static android.os.Parcelable$Creator CREATOR;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}
```

Comment: I didn't accidentally do that; this file was generated automatically.

Comment: It's interesting that it's different from the one I got. What platform did you target when you created the project? (I targeted SDK 1.6.)

Answer (score 0):

The keep-statements are used to prevent proguard from removing classes or class members in the shrinking step and from renaming them in the obfuscation step.

An Activity is a class that you most likely don't want to be romoved from your project. On Android's [ProGuard page](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html) it says

> For some situations, the default configurations in the proguard.cfg file will suffice. However, many situations are hard for ProGuard to analyze correctly and it might remove code that it thinks is not used, but your application actually needs. Some examples include:

- List item a class that is referenced only in the AndroidManifest.xml file

Since that keep part is commented out in the default config I think it is intented, because the out commented *-keep Activities* line would prevent proguard from eliminating any activity.

**In short**: No typo

Comment: It turns out it's not a comment at all.